# AlarmManager set exact repeating interval (without delay) with API>19

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android App which collects data from inertial sensors using a service that I call with AlarmManager each five minutes. This service has a timer to collect data only one minute. So I want to collect one minute of data and sleep four minutes (loop process). The problem is that the AlarmManager with setRepeating() is not exact (one minute delay or more) on API>19. There are a lot of post but not a clear solution... In the MainActivity I have:

```
public void startservice(View view){
    AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorLogger.class);
    PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    scheduler.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000 * 5, scheduledIntent);
}
```

And in the service something like:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new stoptask(), 60000, 60000);

...

return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private class stoptask extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        ...

        timer.cancel();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the repeating api exactly anymore.  You need to set a single exact alarm, then set a new alarm inside that alarm for the repeat.

I posted a library that takes care of multiple timer implementations on android-  take a look at http://gabesechansoftware.com/timers-in-android/ it might help.